# Utiltizing SVN commands from a custom interface

Tags: c#, .net, windows, svn, command-line

I'm looking to automate the GUI available for TortoiseSVN. Rather than using the one provided and manually inputting the urls, I would like to save off various urls that I switch to on a daily basis and at the click of a button switch my working copy to one of my choosing.

TortioseSVN's 'TortioseProc.exe Switch' command does not support the /url parameter until a future release (1.8), this prevents me from being able to embed these easily within an anchor tag (supported by Tortiose) somewhere on our intranet.

Using the standard svn CLI thats compatible with the 1.7 build I'm able to perform switches and automatically close the command line, however I don't know of a way to perform these from a web interface and as I'm not familiar with desktop development I don't know of a plausible desktop solution.

I'm coming to you StackOverflow in hopes you know of a lightweight desktop alternative that wouldn't require much setup on the users side or better yet (web developer by trade) a web solution.

I want to clarify, I'm not looking for actual code but a library or language that will allow me to meet these requirements as I'm hoping to open this solution up to more developers at my workplace and would rather something that allows easy adoption (not a messy setup).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net)?

Comment: Using the svn command line is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Windows/.NET application (whether it be ASP.NET within IIS, or a standalone application), your best way to go is [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net).

Second place would be to write a wrapper around the command-line client.

Comment: Thank you so much, after reading through the documentation this is EXACTLY what I was hoping for.